# Notation for permutation of $n$ objects taken $k$ at a time ( not counting )

Tags: notation

Suppose given $a_1,_2,\cdots,a_n$ , is there a notation for all the permutations missing let's say 1 element ? The need came from trying to expand $\prod (x+a_k)$.
The resulting expansion is easy for the term containing no power of $x$, i.e. $\prod a_k$ , the coefficient of $x$ can be written as $$\sum_{k=1}^n {\frac {\prod_{j=1}^n a_j}{a_k}}$$
but the next term needs to be divided by all the 2 permutations of $a_1,_2,\cdots,a_n$ e.g.
$$\sum_{h=1}^n \sum_{k=1}^n {\frac {\prod_{j=1}^n a_j}{a_ha_k}}$$
trying to make this a little bit more generic
$$\sum_{{\gamma_2}=1}^n \sum_{{\gamma_1}=1}^n {\frac {\prod_{k=1}^n a_k}{a_{\gamma_1} a_{\gamma_2} }}$$
so that coefficient of $x^m$ is

$$\sum_{{\gamma_m}=1}^n \cdots \sum_{{\gamma_2}=1}^n \sum_{{\gamma_1}=1}^n {\frac {\prod_{k=1}^n a_k}{a_{\gamma_1} a_{\gamma_2} \cdots a_{\gamma_m} }}$$

so it seems
$$\prod_{k=1}^n (x+a_k)=  \sum_{m=n}^{m=0} \big(x^{m} \sum_{{\gamma_{m}}=1}^n \cdots \sum_{{\gamma_2}=1}^n \sum_{{\gamma_1}=1}^n {\frac {\prod_{k=1}^n a_k}{a_{\gamma_1} a_{\gamma_2} \cdots a_{\gamma_m} }}\big)$$
but the "$\sum_{{\gamma_{m}}=1}^n \cdots \sum_{{\gamma_2}=1}^n \sum_{{\gamma_1}=1}^n$" part could use a better notation,maybe a way to index the sum itself rather than it's parameters, and having to define how to translate the case for $m=0$ to collapse to $\prod a_k$ .

My question is there a more adapt notation to improve the above issues?

Answer (score 1):

How about
$$\prod_{k=1}^n (x+a_k)=  \sum_{m=n}^{m=0} \big(x^{n-m} \prod_{{\gamma_{1},...,\gamma_{m}: 1\leq\gamma_{1} < ... < \gamma_{m} \leq n}}a_{\gamma_{i}})$$
?
it is not as constructive as your suggestion (though I believe you need to fix your suggestion, as the denominator contains multiple repeats of the same $\alpha$, e.g. $\alpha_1 \alpha_1$, and also different ordering of the same pairs, e.g. you divide both by $\alpha_1 \alpha_2$ and by $\alpha_2 \alpha_1$)

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the duplication